# Reverse geocoding

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
setTimeout("locationplace("+latt+",+"+lonn+")",2000); //line 1
document.write("<tr><td>"+(lc+1) + "</td><td>"+sstime+"</td><td>"+ct+"</td><td>"+minsec+"</td><td><a href='#'>"+loname+"</a></td></tr>"); //line 2
```

AndReverse geocode function is below:

```
function locationplace(latt,lonn)
{
    var rna;
    var llng = new google.maps.LatLng(latt,lonn);
        ligeocoder.geocode({'latLng': llng}, function(results, status)
       {

            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
            { 

                if (results[0]) 
                {
                loname=results[0].formatted_address;
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
            }
        });


}
```

My problem is, In **line 1** the **loname** is ""(empty). I try to use setTimeout..but it is not working....i want to display the **loname**..every time line1 and line 2 executes....

**Also I got error: Geocoder failed due to: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT**

Please help me....

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529746/over-query-limit-while-using-google-maps

Comment: @ram: Was my answer anyhow useful?

Answer (score 1):

1. **OVER_QUERY_LIMIT**: You call the `geocode()` function too often. This is handled in other Stackoverflow topics (see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529746/over-query-limit-while-using-google-maps) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419219/how-do-i-geocode-20-addresses-without-receiving-a-over-query-limit-response) as mentioned in the comment by @OverZealous).
2. `loname` empty: you set `loname` in the callback of `geocode()`. This callback is called asynchronously, so you cannot rely on `loname` being set after calling `locationplace()`:

   ```
   locationplace(...); // calls geocode(), which sets loname asynchronously
   document.write(...loname...) // CANNOT USE HERE
   ```

   The problem is even amplified when you call `locationplace()` in a timetout.

   You should use `loname` in the callback:

   ```
   if (results[0]) {                     
       loname=results[0].formatted_address;
       // use loname here:
       document.write(...loname...)
   }
   ```