# Google Map Javascript API v3 - OVER_QUERY_LIMIT Error

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am displaying multiple locations in the map by iterating a for loop. After doing that few times using Google Map API v3 javascript I am getting this javascript error

Comment: possible duplicate of [OVER_QUERY_LIMIT while using google maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529746/over-query-limit-while-using-google-maps)

Answer (score -1):

This has been answered in the posting below:

[OVER_QUERY_LIMIT while using google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529746/over-query-limit-while-using-google-maps)

To save you a trip: you are being throttled by the API.  Batch the locations and make a single request.