# Google map geocoding stops, while executing recursively

Tags: loops, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

i am using following function to load latlng of addresses From an array to array about 40, but it stops after 10 iterations.

```
 loadStoreLatLong(40);


   function loadStoreLatLong(i){     


    var paddress = store_locations[i]['address'] +','+store_locations[i]['postal_code'] + ', ' +store_locations[i]['district'] + ',' + store_locations[i]['country'];
    var  pgeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    pgeocoder.geocode( { 'address': paddress}, function(results, status) {  
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

        Storelatlong[i] = results[0].geometry.location;
        i--;

        if(i<0){

   clientLocation();

        }else{

   loadStoreLatLong(i);

    //var t = setTimeout("loadStoreLatLong("+(i)+")",1000);
    //jQuery('#map_canvas').text('Loading ... '+i);

        }
        }
    });
}
```

i am really stuck there, can any one help to figure it out, when i set time out 1000, this iterates fine 40 time, when i decrease the timeout, iterations also decreases and stop.    thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client geocoder is not intended for geocoding lots of points on page load.  It is intended for geocoding user entered addresses.

It is asynchronous and is subject to a quota and rate limit.  The limits are set up such that you can geocode ~10 points quickly (depending on server load).

You should check the status returned, if it indicates that you are over the limit, delay for a period of time and retry.

See Andrew's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792916/over-query-limit-in-google-maps-api-v3-how-do-i-pause-delay-in-javascript-to-sl)

Comment: Is there any other library or service that can quick, or any other way ?

Comment: The usual suggestion is to geocode the points offline (not on page load) and use the resulting coordinates, not the geocoder, on page load.

Comment: i have to get points on page load, load all addresses in array and then through loop find latlng of these addresses. can you give me an example, for coordinates and do this will not make issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Geocoder of Google Maps API Javascript is not suite for much points. They denies continuous accesses in short time.

So please use REST version even if you have 40 points.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: "use REST version" i dont understand, can you please guide a bit. some short example.

Comment: How many points do you have? If there are a little points, you can geocoding manually. http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/singlegeocode.html