# What's the best way to control the speed of a loop?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I'm using Google's Geocoder api and I'm hitting the rate limits using the loop below. What's the best approach to slow this down? The `results` array length varies, but doesn't exceed 50 items.

```
for (var key in data) {
var results = data[key];
var address = results['Address'];

//test
if (geocoder) {
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
            { content: '<b>'+address+'</b>',
              size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
            });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            map: map, 
            title:address
        }); 
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });

      } else {
        alert("No results found");
      }
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval)

Comment: possible duplicate of [OVER_QUERY_LIMIT in Google Maps API v3: How do I pause/delay in Javascript to slow it down?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792916/over-query-limit-in-google-maps-api-v3-how-do-i-pause-delay-in-javascript-to-sl)

Comment: @Pointy - Thanks. I thought about that, but wasn't sure if it was appropriate for this.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please tell me why. I'm happy to improve the question if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Put all the code within your loop inside a function called `mySuperCoolLoopFunction` then use this code to call that function at a specified interval:

```
var numberOfMilliseconds = 1000
setInterval(mySuperCoolLoopFunction, numberOfMilliseconds)
```

You can read all about Javascript's setInterval function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) as Pointy pointed out. The first argument is a function, and the second argument is the number of milliseconds to wait before calling the function again.

You can assign the result of the `setInterval` call to a variable and that will allow you to stop the interval at some point. Like this:

```
myInterval = setInterval(coolFunction, 1000)
...
clearInterval(myInterval)
```