# Google Map Geocoded TypeError in Callback function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following 2 functions to pull in, geocode, and place markers in a google map.

I keep getting a `TypeError: adds[i] is undefined`, which of course is causing the rest of the map to bomb.

Here is my code:

```
// Place Markers on the Map
var PlaceMarkers = function (iw, adds, gc) {
    var image = {url: "http://meatmysite.com/Images/star2.png", size: new google.maps.Size(24, 24)};
    var aCt = adds.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < aCt; ++i) {
        GetLatLng(gc, adds[i].address, function(pos) {
            if(pos) {
                var ipop = '<h1>' + adds[i].title + '</h1>'; // <-----   TypeError: adds[i] is undefined
                if(!isBlank(adds[i].url)){
                    ipop += '<a href="' + adds[i].url + '" target="_blank">' + adds[i].url + '</a><br />';
                }
                ipop += '<div class="map_item_content" id="mi_content' + i + '">' + adds[i].content + '</div>';
                if(!isBlank(adds[i].mainphone)){
                    ipop += '<br /><strong>Phone:</strong> <a href="tel:'+adds[i].mainphone+'">' + adds[i].mainphone + '</a>';
                }
                if(!isBlank(adds[i].mainemail)){
                    ipop += '<br /><strong>Email:</strong> <a href="mailto:'+adds[i].mainemail+'">' + adds[i].mainemail + '</a>';
                }
                console.log('HEY NOW: ' + pos.toString() + ' - Location Found!');
                var mark = new google.maps.Marker({title: adds[i].title, position: pos, map: map, icon: image, html: ipop});            
                google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'click', function(){
                    iw.setContent(this.html);
                    iw.open(map, this);
                });
            }
        });
    }
};
// Get Lat/Lng Location
var GetLatLng = function(gc, add, f) {
    var ret = '';
    gc.geocode({'address': add}, function(res, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
            f(res[0].geometry.location);
            console.log('Found Here: ' + ret.toString());
        }
    });
    return -1;
};
```

**DEMO RETURNED DATA FOR adds**

```
[
{
    "address": "1 My Street Gilbert, AZ 85234",
    "title": "My Title 1",
    "url": "http://www.myurl.com/",
    "mainphone": null,
    "mainemail": null,
    "content": "1 My Street<br />Gilbert, AZ 85234"
},
{
    "address": "2 My Street North Richland Hills, TX 76182",
    "title": "My Title 2",
    "url": null,
    "mainphone": null,
    "mainemail": null,
    "content": "2 My Street<br />North Richland Hills, TX 76182"
}
]
```

Comment: an array of location object information, and yes it is populated

Comment: Try changing the order of the incremental on for(var i = 0; i < aCt; ++i)  for this  for(var i = 0; i < aCt; i++)

Comment: no change.  still get the error

Comment: I get an error in your javascript: `Uncaught ReferenceError: isBlank is not defined`, where does that come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, pass the complete "address" object into the `GetLatLng` function, and from there into its callback (so you get function closure on it):

```
// Get Lat/Lng Location
var GetLatLng = function (gc, add, f) {
    gc.geocode({
        'address': add.address
    }, function (res, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
            f(res[0].geometry.location, add);
        }
    });
};
```

Then use it like this inside the callback (you could pass just the index into the array also):

```
GetLatLng(gc, adds[i], function (pos, add) {
    if (pos) {
        var ipop = '<h1>' + add.title + '</h1>'; 
        if (!isBlank(add.url)) {
            ipop += '<a href="' + add.url + '" target="_blank">' + add.url + '</a><br />';
        }
        ipop += '<div class="map_item_content" id="mi_content' + i + '">' + add.content + '</div>';
        if (!isBlank(add.mainphone)) {
            ipop += '<br /><strong>Phone:</strong> <a href="tel:' + add.mainphone + '">' + add.mainphone + '</a>';
        }
        if (!isBlank(add.mainemail)) {
            ipop += '<br /><strong>Email:</strong> <a href="mailto:' + add.mainemail + '">' + add.mainemail + '</a>';
        }
        console.log('HEY NOW: ' + pos.toString() + ' - Location Found!');
        var mark = new google.maps.Marker({
            title: add.title,
            position: pos,
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            html: ipop
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'click', function () {
            iw.setContent(this.html);
            iw.open(map, this);
        });
    }
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/195b51ng/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var map;
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  PlaceMarkers(infoWindow, adds, geocoder);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

// Place Markers on the Map
var PlaceMarkers = function(iw, adds, gc) {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var image = {
    url: "http://meatmysite.com/Images/star2.png",
    size: new google.maps.Size(24, 24)
  };
  var aCt = adds.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < aCt; ++i) {
    GetLatLng(gc, adds[i], function(pos, add) {
      if (pos) {
        var ipop = '<h1>' + add.title + '</h1>'; // <-----   TypeError: adds[i] is undefined
        if (!isBlank(add.url)) {
          ipop += '<a href="' + add.url + '" target="_blank">' + add.url + '</a><br />';
        }
        ipop += '<div class="map_item_content" id="mi_content' + i + '">' + add.content + '</div>';
        if (!isBlank(add.mainphone)) {
          ipop += '<br /><strong>Phone:</strong> <a href="tel:' + add.mainphone + '">' + add.mainphone + '</a>';
        }
        if (!isBlank(add.mainemail)) {
          ipop += '<br /><strong>Email:</strong> <a href="mailto:' + add.mainemail + '">' + add.mainemail + '</a>';
        }
        console.log('HEY NOW: ' + pos.toString() + ' - Location Found!');
        var mark = new google.maps.Marker({
          title: add.title,
          position: pos,
          map: map,
          // icon: image,
          html: ipop
        });
        bounds.extend(mark.getPosition());
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'click', function() {
          iw.setContent(this.html);
          iw.open(map, this);
        });
      }
    });
  }
};
// Get Lat/Lng Location
var GetLatLng = function(gc, add, f) {
  gc.geocode({
    'address': add.address
  }, function(res, status) {
    if (status == 'OK') {
      f(res[0].geometry.location, add);
    }
  });
};

var adds = [{
  "address": "1 My Street Gilbert, AZ 85234",
  "title": "My Title 1",
  "url": "http://www.myurl.com/",
  "mainphone": null,
  "mainemail": null,
  "content": "1 My Street<br />Gilbert, AZ 85234"
}, {
  "address": "2 My Street North Richland Hills, TX 76182",
  "title": "My Title 2",
  "url": null,
  "mainphone": null,
  "mainemail": null,
  "content": "2 My Street<br />North Richland Hills, TX 76182"
}];

function isBlank(str) {
  return (!str || /^\s*$/.test(str));
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate for the help with this.
Now if there is some way I can over-come this "limit" of # of marks shown, I'll be golden.  I have a total of 21 addresses to mark on the map, but only 11 are showing....   no errors :)

Comment: That is another question, possible duplicate of [OVER_QUERY_LIMIT in Google Maps API v3: How do I pause/delay in Javascript to slow it down?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792916/over-query-limit-in-google-maps-api-v3-how-do-i-pause-delay-in-javascript-to-sl)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a typical binding issue. By the time your callback is called, the value of `adds[i]` will have changed. It is likely that the loop terminated and `i` has now a value of `last index + 1`, which is pointing to nothing. Note that it could also point to the wrong index, that would not fail but use the wrong data.

You must bind the value of `adds[i]` locally for each iteration or the callback will just use a reference to a global value. There a multiple ways to go about this, here is a simple one where we keep passing `adds[i]` along as a function argument.

Replace `adds[i].address` with `adds[i]` when calling `GetLatLng` and add a second parameter `add` to the callback:

```
GetLatLng(gc, adds[i], function(pos, add) {
    ...
});
```

Then modify `GetLatLng` to use `add.address` instead of just `add` and add `add` to the callback call:

```
// Get Lat/Lng Location
var GetLatLng = function(gc, add, f) {
    var ret = '';
    gc.geocode({'address': add.address}, function(res, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
            f(res[0].geometry.location, add);
            console.log('Found Here: ' + ret.toString());
        }
    });
    return -1;
};
```

Then in the callback function, replace all instances of `adds[i]` with `add` to use the local variable.

I didn't set up a test but it should theoretically work.

Answer (score 0):

you appear to be overcomplicating things. Any reason why you can't do this?

```
// Place Markers on the Map
var PlaceMarkers = function (iw, adds, gc) {
    var aCt = adds.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < aCt; ++i) {
    var obj=adds[i];
        GetLatLng(gc, obj)
    }
};

// Get Lat/Lng Location
var GetLatLng = function(gc, obj) {
    var ret = '';
    gc.geocode({'address': obj.address}, function(res, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
        var pos=res[0].geometry.location;
            var ipop = '<h1>' + obj.title + '</h1>'; // <-----   TypeError: adds[i] is undefined
                if(!isBlank(obj.url)){
                    ipop += '<a href="' + obj.url + '" target="_blank">' + obj.url + '</a><br />';
                }
                ipop += '<div class="map_item_content" id="mi_content">' + obj.content + '</div>';
                if(!isBlank(obj.mainphone)){
                    ipop += '<br /><strong>Phone:</strong> <a href="tel:'+obj.mainphone+'">' + obj.mainphone + '</a>';
                }
                if(!isBlank(obj.mainemail)){
                    ipop += '<br /><strong>Email:</strong> <a href="mailto:'+obj.mainemail+'">' + obj.mainemail + '</a>';
                }
                console.log('HEY NOW: ' + pos.toString() + ' - Location Found!');
                var mark = new google.maps.Marker({title: obj.title, position: pos, map: map, html: ipop});                 
                google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'click', function(){
                    iw.setContent(this.html);
                    iw.open(map, this);
                });
        } else {
        console.log("geocoder problem!")
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

`for(var i = 0; i < aCt - 1; ++i)`. You need to add "-1" in you for-loop. The array starts at index 0 and not 1. You also need to be careful with using functions in a for loop. Within javascript a for-loop does not have a scope from itself. Only functions create new scopes.