# Why is status OVER_QUERY_LIMIT running before Status.OK - Google Maps API

Tags: jquery, function, google-maps-api-3, delay, timedelay

Why is status OVER_QUERY_LIMIT running before Status.OK? I use this code:

```
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        var response = Math.ceil(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000);

        stores.push({
            distance: response,
            id: item.properties.Nid,
        });

        console.log('STATUS.OK');
    } else if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT){
        console.log('OVER_QUERY_LIMIT');
    }
});
```

Status OVER_QUERY_LIMIT is logged before the STATUS.OK. I know that OVER_QUERY_LIMIT is running because I did to many requests.

But I can't figure how I could create a delay when OVER_QUERY_LIMIT is always running first.

Can someone explain it to me please?

Answer (score 2):

The request is asynchronous.  It takes more time to generate the data for a status="OK" response than it does to return the status="OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" response.

You need to handle the **request** that resulted in the "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" status as is done in the related question: [OVER_QUERY_LIMIT in Google Maps API v3: How do I pause/delay in Javascript to slow it down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792916/over-query-limit-in-google-maps-api-v3-how-do-i-pause-delay-in-javascript-to-sl)