# Google Maps JavaScript API V3 - Display multiple routes

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to display multiple routes using the google maps API.
But when trying with more than 10 routes I get an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT exception.

Using google, I found out, that I need to call DirectionsDisplay asynchronously using the callback function (couldn't get this to work yet). And that I have to use some sort of timeout because you can't make more than 10 requests per second.

Heres what I got so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Display multiple routes</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=ENTER_API_KEY"></script>


    <style>
        /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
        * element that contains the map. */
        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
        /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>

        var addresses =
            [
                ['243, Dornacherstrasse', '26, Mattenstrasse'],
                ['48 av general de gaulle, saint louis', 'Gründenstraße 40, Muttenz'],
                ['50 ackerstrasse , Basel', 'holeestrasse 133, Basel'],
                ['71 avenue de Bâle , Saint-Louis ', 'Leonhardstr 6, Basel'],
                ['Ackerstrasse 44, Basel', 'Petersplatz 1, Basel'],
                ['Ackerstrasse 51, Basel', 'Maiengasse 51, Basel '],
                ['Aeussere Baselstr. 255, Riehen', 'zu den drei Linden 80, Basel'],
                ['Aeussere Baselstrasse 309, Riehen', 'Gotthelfplatz 1, Basel'],
                ['Ahornstrasse 20, Basel', 'Viaduktstrasse , Basel'],
                ['Albert Schweitzer Strasse 10, Basel', 'Kohlenberg 17, Basel'],
                ['alemannengasse 17, Basel', 'Centrahlbahnplatz, Basel'],
                ['Alemannengasse 23, Basel', 'Peter Merian-Weg 8, Basel'],
                ['Allmendstrasse 233, Basel', 'Universitätsspital Basel, Basel '],
                ['Allmendstrasse 4, Basel', 'Petersplatz 1, Basel'],
                ['Allschwilerstrasse 106, Basel', 'Centralbahnstrasse 10 , Basel'],
                ['Allschwilerstrasse 116, Basel', 'Spitalstrasse 8, Architektur Institut, Basel '],
                ['Allschwilerstrasse 116, Basel', 'Steinenvorstadt 55, Kino Pathè Küchlin, Basel'],
                ['Allschwilerstrasse 48, Basel', 'Schneidergasse 28, Basel'],
                ['Altrheinweg 52, Basel', 'Vogesenplatz 1, Basel '],
                ['Am Rheinpark 6, Weil am Rhein', 'J. J. Balmer-Str. 3, Basel'],
                ['Am Weiher 15, Binningen', 'Klingelbergstrasse 82, Basel '],
                ['Amerbachstrasse, , Basel', 'Peter Merian-Weg, Basel'],
                ['Amerikanerstrasse 16, Binningen', 'Petersplatz 1, Basel'],
                ['Amselweg 20, Reinach', 'Baselstrasse 33, Münchenstein'],
                ['An der Auhalde 15, Riehen', 'Zu den Dreilinden 95, Basel'],
                ['arnikastr. 22, Riehen', 'marktplatz, Basel'],
                ['Auf der Lyss 14, Basel', 'Grenzstrasse 15, Basel']
            ];

        var directionsDisplay;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var map;

        function initialize() {
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            var basel = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 7,
                center: basel
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        }

        function calcRoute(start, end) {

            var request = {
                origin: start,
                destination: end,
                travelMode: 'BICYCLING'
            };
            directionsService.route(request,
                function(result, status) {
                    if (status == 'OK') {

                        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                            suppressBicyclingLayer: true,
                            suppressMarkers: true
                        });
                        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                    }
                });
        }

        initialize();
        addresses.forEach(function (v, i) {
            setTimeout(calcRoute(addresses[i][0], addresses[i][1]), 100);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm aware that there are a lot of similar questions on SO. But none of them worked for me.

Comment: A question should actually contain a question. In which similar question did you see it implemented like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using modified code from the related answer [OVER_QUERY_LIMIT in Google Maps API v3: How do I pause/delay in Javascript to slow it down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792916/over-query-limit-in-google-maps-api-v3-how-do-i-pause-delay-in-javascript-to-sl) which solves the same issue with the Google Maps Javascript API v3 Geocoder by detecting the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT status and increasing the delay between requests when it occurs.

```
// delay between directions requests
var delay = 100;

function calcRoute(start, end, next) {
  console.log("calcRoute('" + start + "','" + end + "',next)");
  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: 'BICYCLING'
  };
  directionsService.route(request,
    function(result, status) {
      if (status == 'OK') {

        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
          suppressBicyclingLayer: true,
          suppressMarkers: true,
          preserveViewport: true // don't zoom to fit the route
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        // combine the bounds of the responses
        bounds.union(result.routes[0].bounds);
        // zoom and center the map to show all the routes
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
      }
      // ====== Decode the error status ======
      else {
        console.log("status=" + status + " (start=" + start + ", end=" + end + ")");
        // === if we were sending the requests to fast, try this one again and increase the delay
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
          nextAddress--;
          delay += 100;
          document.getElementById('delay').innerHTML = delay;
        } else {
          var reason = "Code " + status;
          var msg = 'start="' + start + ' end="' + end + '"" error=' + reason + '(delay=' + delay + 'ms)<br>';
          document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += msg;
        }
      }
      next();
    });
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/c1tpo1ua/15/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var addresses = [
  ['243, Dornacherstrasse', '26, Mattenstrasse'],
  ['48 av general de gaulle, saint louis', 'Gründenstraße 40, Muttenz'],
  ['50 ackerstrasse , Basel', 'holeestrasse 133, Basel'],
  ['71 avenue de Bâle , Saint-Louis ', 'Leonhardstr 6, Basel'],
  ['Ackerstrasse 44, Basel', 'Petersplatz 1, Basel'],
  ['Ackerstrasse 51, Basel', 'Maiengasse 51, Basel '],
  ['Aeussere Baselstr. 255, Riehen', 'zu den drei Linden 80, Basel'],
  ['Aeussere Baselstrasse 309, Riehen', 'Gotthelfplatz 1, Basel'],
  ['Ahornstrasse 20, Basel', 'Viaduktstrasse , Basel'],
  ['Albert Schweitzer Strasse 10, Basel', 'Kohlenberg 17, Basel'],
  ['alemannengasse 17, Basel', 'Centrahlbahnplatz, Basel'],
  ['Alemannengasse 23, Basel', 'Peter Merian-Weg 8, Basel'],
  ['Allmendstrasse 233, Basel', 'Universitätsspital Basel, Basel '],
  ['Allmendstrasse 4, Basel', 'Petersplatz 1, Basel'],
  ['Allschwilerstrasse 106, Basel', 'Centralbahnstrasse 10 , Basel'],
  ['Allschwilerstrasse 116, Basel', 'Spitalstrasse 8, Architektur Institut, Basel '],
  ['Allschwilerstrasse 116, Basel', 'Steinenvorstadt 55, Kino Pathè Küchlin, Basel'],
  ['Allschwilerstrasse 48, Basel', 'Schneidergasse 28, Basel'],
  ['Altrheinweg 52, Basel', 'Vogesenplatz 1, Basel '],
  ['Am Rheinpark 6, Weil am Rhein', 'J. J. Balmer-Str. 3, Basel'],
  ['Am Weiher 15, Binningen', 'Klingelbergstrasse 82, Basel '],
  ['Amerbachstrasse, , Basel', 'Peter Merian-Weg, Basel'],
  ['Amerikanerstrasse 16, Binningen', 'Petersplatz 1, Basel'],
  ['Amselweg 20, Reinach', 'Baselstrasse 33, Münchenstein'],
  ['An der Auhalde 15, Riehen', 'Zu den Dreilinden 95, Basel'],
  ['arnikastr. 22, Riehen', 'marktplatz, Basel'],
  ['Auf der Lyss 14, Basel', 'Grenzstrasse 15, Basel']
];

var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var bounds;

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var basel = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: basel
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
}

// delay between directions requests
var delay = 100;

function calcRoute(start, end, next) {
  console.log("calcRoute('" + start + "','" + end + "',next)");
  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: 'BICYCLING'
  };
  directionsService.route(request,
    function(result, status) {
      if (status == 'OK') {

        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
          suppressBicyclingLayer: true,
          suppressMarkers: true,
          preserveViewport: true // don't zoom to fit the route
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        // combine the bounds of the responses
        bounds.union(result.routes[0].bounds);
        // zoom and center the map to show all the routes
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
      }
      // ====== Decode the error status ======
      else {
        console.log("status=" + status + " (start=" + start + ", end=" + end + ")");
        // === if we were sending the requests to fast, try this one again and increase the delay
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
          nextAddress--;
          delay += 100;
          document.getElementById('delay').innerHTML = "delay between requests=" + delay;
        } else {
          var reason = "Code " + status;
          var msg = 'start="' + start + ' end="' + end + '"" error=' + reason + '(delay=' + delay + 'ms)<br>';
          document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += msg;
        }
      }
      next();
    });
}

initialize();
// ======= Global variable to remind us what to do next
var nextAddress = 0;

// ======= Function to call the next Geocode operation when the reply comes back

function theNext() {
  if (nextAddress < addresses.length) {
    console.log('call calcRoute("' + addresses[nextAddress][0] + '","' + addresses[nextAddress][1] + ') delay=' + delay);
    setTimeout('calcRoute("' + addresses[nextAddress][0] + '","' + addresses[nextAddress][1] + '",theNext)', delay);
    nextAddress++;
  } else {
    // We're done. Show map bounds
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
}

// ======= Call that function for the first time =======
theNext();

// This Javascript is based on code provided by the
// Community Church Javascript Team
// https://www.bisphamchurch.org.uk/   
// https://econym.org.uk/gmap/
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="delay"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="messages"></div>
```