# Another Google Maps Geocoding Issue

Tags: javascript, maps, geocode

I am really hoping someone can help me as I've been hitting my head against a wall for hours now.

A few weeks ago after trawling around various sites (mainly this one haha), I put together a bit of javascript that allowed a formidable pro database within a WordPress site to send its data to be geocoded with google and displayed on a map. It does this by passing the data into a variable using a php shortcode (nothing fancy), allowing me to specify the postcode and what text I want it to display when you click it.

Code Below:

```js
var locations = [<?php echo FrmProDisplaysController::get_shortcode( array( 'id' => 21529, 'wpautop' => '0' ) ); ?>];
var mapOptions = {center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5, -0.12),zoom: 10,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var marker, i;for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    codeAddress(locations[i]);
}

function codeAddress(location) {
    geocoder.geocode({'address': location[1]}, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                title: location[1],
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
            bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, location) {
                return function () {
                    infowindow.setContent(location[0]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                };
            })(marker, location));
        }
    });
}
```

Everything worked great...except the code I had got to work did not take into account the limits on the number of requests per second.

I've been looking around and found this [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792916/over-query-limit-in-google-maps-api-v3-how-do-i-pause-delay-in-javascript-to-sl/11825245) on here on how to fix the issue by Andrew Leach and have got this one to work also.

But this solution does not allow me to specify what text I want it to display for each entry.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me adjust either code to solve either issue?

Thank you in advance for your time and effort.

All the best

Richard

Comment: Please stick to a single query per question.

Comment: Apologies, I have been working on this issue for a number of days and to me it seems like one issue as I have been working through.  I just have two solutions to the same problem, but neither satisfies.

Comment: I thought it best to post both solutions so far as they try to answer the same problem, rather than each one individually as someone might be able to see a solution and my train of thought better than I can.