# Google Map markers Infobox in exact same location

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am not a programmer or a developer. I am facing a problem that the google map infobox not display when they are in exact same location, (geocodezip) have a very good solution, however I don't know how to modify my code.

This is my code

```
(function ($) {
var settings;
var element;
var map;
var markers = new Array();
var markerCluster;
var clustersOnMap = new Array();
var clusterListener;

var methods = {
    init: function (options) {
        element = $(this);

        var defaults = $.extend({
            enableGeolocation: false,
            pixelOffsetX     : -145,
            pixelOffsetY     : -200
        });

        settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        google.maps.Map.prototype.setCenterWithOffset = function (latlng, offsetX, offsetY) {
            var map = this;
            var ov = new google.maps.OverlayView();

            ov.onAdd = function () {
                var proj = this.getProjection();
                var aPoint = proj.fromLatLngToContainerPixel(latlng);
                aPoint.x = aPoint.x + offsetX;
                aPoint.y = aPoint.y + offsetY;
                map.setCenter(proj.fromContainerPixelToLatLng(aPoint));
            }

            ov.draw = function () {
            };
            ov.setMap(this);
        };

        google.maps.visualRefresh = true;

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', loadMap);

        if (settings.filterForm && $(settings.filterForm).length !== 0) {
            $(settings.filterForm).submit(function (e) {
                var form = $(this);
                var action = $(this).attr('action');

                $.ajax({
                    type   : 'GET',
                    url    : action,
                    data   : form.serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        element.aviators_map('removeMarkers');
                        element.aviators_map('addMarkers', {
                            locations: eval(data.locations),
                            types    : eval(data.types),
                            contents : eval(data.contents)
                        });
                    }
                });

                e.preventDefault();
            });
        }


        if (options.callback) {
            options.callback();
        }
        return $(this);
    },

    removeMarkers: function () {
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            markers[i].infobox.close();
            markers[i].marker.close();
            markers[i].setMap(null);
        }

        markerCluster.clearMarkers();

        $.each(clustersOnMap, function (index, cluster) {
            cluster.cluster.close();
        });

        clusterListener.remove();
    },

    addMarkers: function (options) {
        markers = new Array();
        settings.locations = options.locations;
        settings.contents = options.contents;
        settings.types = options.types;

        renderElements();
    }
}

$.fn.aviators_map = function (method) {
    // Method calling logic
    if (methods[method]) {
        return methods[ method ].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on Aviators Map');
    }
};

function loadMap() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom              : settings.zoom,
        mapTypeId         : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        scrollwheel       : false,
        draggable         : true,
        mapTypeControl    : false,
        panControl        : false,
        zoomControl       : true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style   : google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
        }
    };

    if (settings.enableGeolocation) {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            browserSupportFlag = true;
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                map.setCenter(initialLocation);
            }, function () {
                mapOptions.center = new google.maps.LatLng(settings.center.latitude, settings.center.longitude);
            });
        } else {
            browserSupportFlag = false;
            mapOptions.center = new google.maps.LatLng(settings.center.latitude, settings.center.longitude);
        }
    } else {
        mapOptions.center = new google.maps.LatLng(settings.center.latitude, settings.center.longitude);
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map($(element)[0], mapOptions);

    var dragFlag = false;
    var start = 0, end = 0;

    function thisTouchStart(e) {
        dragFlag = true;
        start = e.touches[0].pageY;
    }

    function thisTouchEnd() {
        dragFlag = false;
    }

    function thisTouchMove(e) {
        if (!dragFlag) {
            return
        }

        end = e.touches[0].pageY;
        window.scrollBy(0, ( start - end ));
    }

    var el = $('#map')[0];

    if (el.addEventListener) {
        el.addEventListener('touchstart', thisTouchStart, true);
        el.addEventListener('touchend', thisTouchEnd, true);
        el.addEventListener('touchmove', thisTouchMove, true);
    } else if (el.attachEvent){
        el.attachEvent('touchstart', thisTouchStart);
        el.attachEvent('touchend', thisTouchEnd);
        el.attachEvent('touchmove', thisTouchMove);
    }

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
        $.each(markers, function (index, marker) {
            marker.infobox.close();
            marker.infobox.isOpen = false;
        });
    });

    renderElements();

    $('.infobox .close').live('click', function () {
        $.each(markers, function (index, marker) {
            marker.infobox.close();
            marker.infobox.isOpen = false;
        });
    });
}

function isClusterOnMap(clustersOnMap, cluster) {
    if (cluster === undefined) {
        return false;
    }

    if (clustersOnMap.length == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    var val = false;

    $.each(clustersOnMap, function (index, cluster_on_map) {
        if (cluster_on_map.getCenter() == cluster.getCenter()) {
            val = cluster_on_map;
        }
    });

    return val;
}

function addClusterOnMap(cluster) {
    // Hide all cluster's markers
    $.each(cluster.getMarkers(), (function () {
        if (this.marker.isHidden == false) {
            this.marker.isHidden = true;
            this.marker.close();
        }
    }));

    var newCluster = new InfoBox({
        markers               : cluster.getMarkers(),
        draggable             : true,
        content               : '<div class="clusterer"><div class="clusterer-inner">' + cluster.getMarkers().length + '</div></div>',
        disableAutoPan        : true,
        pixelOffset           : new google.maps.Size(-21, -21),
        position              : cluster.getCenter(),
        closeBoxURL           : "",
        isHidden              : false,
        enableEventPropagation: true,
        pane                  : "mapPane"
    });

    cluster.cluster = newCluster;

    cluster.markers = cluster.getMarkers();
    cluster.cluster.open(map, cluster.marker);
    clustersOnMap.push(cluster);
}

function renderElements() {

    $.each(settings.locations, function (index, location) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[0], location[1]),
            map     : map,
            icon    : settings.transparentMarkerImage
        });

        marker.infobox = new InfoBox({
            content               : settings.contents[index],
            disableAutoPan        : false,
            maxWidth              : 0,
            pixelOffset           : new google.maps.Size(settings.pixelOffsetX, settings.pixelOffsetY),
            zIndex                : null,
            closeBoxURL           : "",
            infoBoxClearance      : new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
            position              : new google.maps.LatLng(location[0], location[1]),
            isHidden              : false,
            pane                  : "floatPane",
            enableEventPropagation: false
        });
        marker.infobox.isOpen = false;

        marker.marker = new InfoBox({
            draggable             : true,
            content               : '<div class="marker ' + settings.types[index] + '"><div class="marker-inner"></div></div>',
            disableAutoPan        : true,
            pixelOffset           : new google.maps.Size(-21, -58),
            position              : new google.maps.LatLng(location[0], location[1]),
            closeBoxURL           : "",
            isHidden              : false,
            pane                  : "floatPane",
            enableEventPropagation: true
        });
        marker.marker.isHidden = false;
        marker.marker.open(map, marker);
        markers.push(marker);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (e) {
            var curMarker = this;

            $.each(markers, function (index, marker) {
                // if marker is not the clicked marker, close the marker
                if (marker !== curMarker) {
                    marker.infobox.close();
                    marker.infobox.isOpen = false;
                }
            });

            if (curMarker.infobox.isOpen === false) {
                curMarker.infobox.open(map, this);
                curMarker.infobox.isOpen = true;
                map.setCenterWithOffset(curMarker.getPosition(), 100, -120);
            } else {
                curMarker.infobox.close();
                curMarker.infobox.isOpen = false;
            }
        });
    });

    markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
        gridSize: 40,
        styles: [
            {
                height   : 42,
                url      : settings.transparentClusterImage,
                width    : 42,
                textColor: 'transparent'
            }
        ]
    });

    clustersOnMap = new Array();

    clusterListener = google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'clusteringend', function (clusterer) {
        var availableClusters = clusterer.getClusters();
        var activeClusters = new Array();

        $.each(availableClusters, function (index, cluster) {
            if (cluster.getMarkers().length > 1) {
                activeClusters.push(cluster);
            }
        });

        $.each(availableClusters, function (index, cluster) {
            if (cluster.getMarkers().length > 1) {
                var val = isClusterOnMap(clustersOnMap, cluster);

                if (val !== false) {
                    val.cluster.setContent('<div class="clusterer"><div class="clusterer-inner">' + cluster.getMarkers().length + '</div></div>');
                    val.markers = cluster.getMarkers();
                    $.each(cluster.getMarkers(), (function (index, marker) {
                        if (marker.marker.isHidden == false) {
                            marker.marker.isHidden = true;
                            marker.marker.close();
                        }
                    }));
                } else {
                    addClusterOnMap(cluster);
                }
            } else {
                // Show all markers without the cluster
                $.each(cluster.getMarkers(), function (index, marker) {
                    if (marker.marker.isHidden == true) {
                        marker.marker.open(map, this);
                        marker.marker.isHidden = false;
                    }
                });

                // Remove old cluster
                $.each(clustersOnMap, function (index, cluster_on_map) {
                    if (cluster !== undefined && cluster_on_map !== undefined) {
                        if (cluster_on_map.getCenter() == cluster.getCenter()) {
                            // Show all cluster's markers/
                            cluster_on_map.cluster.close();
                            clustersOnMap.splice(index, 1);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        var newClustersOnMap = new Array();

        $.each(clustersOnMap, function (index, clusterOnMap) {
            var remove = true;

            $.each(availableClusters, function (index2, availableCluster) {
                if (availableCluster.getCenter() == clusterOnMap.getCenter()) {
                    remove = false;
                }
            });

            if (!remove) {
                newClustersOnMap.push(clusterOnMap);
            } else {
                clusterOnMap.cluster.close();
            }
        });

        clustersOnMap = newClustersOnMap;
    });
}
})(jQuery);
```

and This is geocodezip code

[Google Maps Multiple markers with the exact same location Not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708252/google-maps-multiple-markers-with-the-exact-same-location-not-working/19476265#19476265)

Many Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That solution is great, but I'd take a look at using the [Overlapping Marker Spiderfier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier) library to handle markers in the same location. You can use this in conjunction with the marker clusterer library, without any issues. This way you also don't lose the ability to see how many markers are actually in that same location - and it gives you a great UI in my opinion.

To use Overlapping Marker Spiderfier, include the script file before your main js file in your html. Then in your js, create an instance of the `OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier` object:

```
var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map); 
/*in your case I'd do this after you initialize the `map` object, 
 *and declare the `oms` globally, like you do with your other global objects
 */
```

Then when the markers are created, you want to add the marker to the `oms` object via the `addMarker()` method. So, in your case add the following line to the `renderElements()` function after the `click` event listener you declare for the `marker`:

```
oms.addMarker(marker);
```

Lastly, make sure to also clear the markers from the `oms` object when the `removeMarkers()` function in your code is called by adding the following to that function:

```
oms.clearMarkers();
```