# MarkerclustererPlus - returning array of markers to a cluster info window

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow, markerclusterer

I am using [Markerclustererplus](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html) with Google Maps API v3 to ease the display of markers on the screen.

The problem is that I will have several markers in the exact same place (and it should be that way) and I would like to, when clicking on a cluster, to display an info window containing all the markers that were clustered.

I've tried several code and similar questions here in StackOverflow, unfortunately I do not master JS and couldn't solve this.

Markers are pushed into an array with some data:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position : latlng,
map      : map,
icon     : marker_image 
});

map.markers.push(marker);
```

When I click an isolated marker, the info window appears ok with a title and an image of that marker:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content : $marker.attr('data-title') + '<img width="50" src="' + $marker.attr('data-image') + '">'
    });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open( map, marker );
    });
```

What I would like to happen, is that when clicker a cluster, an info window would open with all of the markers it contains displayed with their corresponding title and image (like, reversing the clustering operation).

Thank you for the help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps Multiple markers with the exact same location Not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708252/google-maps-multiple-markers-with-the-exact-same-location-not-working)

Comment: thanks for pointing me... having trouble figuring this out from the link given, but will try

Comment: Trying but still can't figure it out. I have two .js files (one acf_maps.js, which is basically the one available in [link](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/google-map/) and that grabs some variables from the Advanced Custom Fields plugin (using this in Wordpress); and the other is the markerclustererplus.js, available here: [link](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/src/markerclusterer.js). @geocodezip :can you please tell me where should I add the code that is found in the similar question you've pointed out? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Managed to solve this, thanks to the example provided in [here](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_markerclustererplus_examples_simple_exampleA.html?).

If anyone is interested, here is how I've done:

First, I've added the markers to the map getting data attributes coming from several custom fields from Wordpress custom posts:

```
function add_marker( $marker, map ) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng') );
    var marker_image = $marker.attr('data-marker');
    var marker_name = $marker.attr('data-title');
    var marker_userpicture = $marker.attr('data-image');
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position        : latlng,
    map             : map,
    icon            : marker_image,
    name            : marker_name,
    userpicture     : marker_userpicture
    });

map.markers.push(marker);
```

Created the MarkerCluster:

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, map.markers, mcOptions);
```

Added a click event listener that got the markers from the cluster, their data, created the info window content from that data and finally opened the info window:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'click', function(cluster){
var content ='';
var clickedMarkers = cluster.getMarkers();

for (var i = 0; i < clickedMarkers.length; i++) {
    if(i==0) {
    var var_pos = clickedMarkers[i];
    }

    var clickedMarkersNames = clickedMarkers[i].name;
    var clickedMarkersPicture = clickedMarkers[i].userpicture;
    content +=clickedMarkersNames;
    content +=clickedMarkersPicture;
}

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
infowindow.setContent(content);
infowindow.open(map,var_pos);
});
```