# Google maps api geocoding not working

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, geocoding

I am working on a project in CodeIgniter and I require `lat` and `lng` of a specific location. The code at the bottom was working fine but now `$geo['status']` is showing `QUERY_OVER_LIMIT`. How to solve it?

I also get the following warning:

> `undefined offset:0 error in $latlng['lat']= $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']; $latlng['lng']= $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];`

Thanks in advance. Here's my code:

```
$address = $this->input->post('key');
$geo = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geoco/json?address='.urlencode($address).'&sensor=false');
$geo = json_decode($geo, true);

if ($geo['status'] = 'OK') {
    $latlng['lat']= $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
    $latlng['lng']= $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
    echo json_encode($latlng);
} else {
    echo 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OVER\_QUERY\_LIMIT while using google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529746/over-query-limit-while-using-google-maps)

Comment: You exceeded the limit! There's no error, it's just that you used more than you're allowed to. [Learn more in this page...](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/articles/usage-limits)

Comment: And to add on to what everyone else has said see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding which shows you are limited to 2500 requests a day with no more than 50 requests a second.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Is there any solution for that @IsThisJavascript

Comment: Add a count to your loop, once you reach 50, sleep for a second then carry on looping.

Comment: but the main thing is I am not using any kind of loop here

Comment: Do you believe you've hit the limit of 2500 requests a day?

Comment: Obviously not that's why I am confused

Comment: By the way, shouldn't `$latlng['lng']= $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];` be `$latlng['lng']= $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];`? I mean, both assignments take `lat`, but the second should take `lng`, am I right?

Comment: Wait, I’m confused, what worked? What I said shouldn’t have fixed anything related to the limit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your check for `$geo['status'] = 'OK'` will always be 'OK' because you have used a single "=" instead of "==".

This means that even if the google response was something other than what you'd expect, you're still proceeding into that code block.

```
<?php

$row = [
    'address' => '1315 10th St.',
    'city'    => 'Sacramento',
    'state'   => 'CA',
    'zip'     => '95814'
];

$address = str_replace(' ', '+', $row['address'] ) . ',' 
    . str_replace(' ', '+', $row['city'] ) . ',' 
    . str_replace(' ', '+', $row['state'] ) . ',' 
    . str_replace(' ', '+', $row['zip'] );

function get_gps_coordinates_of_street_address( $address )
{
    $url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' 
                    . $address;

    if( $response = @file_get_contents( $url ) )
    {
        $geo = json_decode( $response, TRUE );

        if( $geo['status'] == 'OK' )
        {
            return $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'] . ',' . $arr['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
        }
        else
        {
            return 'GPS coordinates were not available for supplied ADDRESS';
        }

    }
    else
    {
        return 'GPS coordinates were not available because connection failed or malformed request';
    }
}

var_dump( get_gps_coordinates_of_street_address( $address ) );
```