# GMap Geocoding: Over query limit

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

I have a little problem about Google Maps. I'm using Geocoding (xml) for getting address from Google Map. I give the address and Geocoding gives me long-latt values.
And when I try to bind many location Google map just shows 11 location, not more.
And it gives an warning like

> "Over query limit"

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google limits the number of geocoding requests per second. You can either wait or cache the results somewhere in your own database.

See this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419219/how-do-i-geocode-20-addresses-without-receiving-a-over-query-limit-response?rq=1).