# Google Maps API OVER QUERY LIMIT per second limit

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps API to display about 50 locations on the map. I am using client side geocoding. I am using window.setTimeout to control the number of geocode requests that the application sends per second. If I send more than 1 request per second, I am getting an OVER QUERY LIMIT response.

**Question: Isn't this limit supposed to be 10 queries per second? If yes, then what could I be doing wrong? If no, then does Business API has more generous queries per second limit?**

Please note that our application is not going to hit the 25,000 queries per day.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The geocoder has quota and rate limits.  From experience, you can geocode ~10 locations without hitting the query limit (the actual number probably depends on server loading). The best solution is to delay when you get OVER_QUERY_LIMIT errors, then retry. See these similar posts:

- [OVER_QUERY_LIMIT in Google Maps API v3: How do I pause/delay in Javascript to slow it down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792916/over-query-limit-in-google-maps-api-v3-how-do-i-pause-delay-in-javascript-to-sl)
- [How do I Geocode 20 addresses without receiving an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419219/how-do-i-geocode-20-addresses-without-receiving-an-over-query-limit-response)

Comment: Thanks geocodezip. I did try delaying it using window.setTimeout but it worked only with a delay of 1 second. Now, I changed the code so that I issue the geocode requests until I get an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT response. After that I pause for 3 secondsd and then repeat. This strategy seems to resolve 50 requests in a about 26 seconds (rather than 50 seconds). I am all ears if there is a better strategy.

Answer (score 5):

Often when you need to show so many points on the map, you'd be better off using the server-side approach, this article explains when to use each:

Geocoding Strategies: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat

The client-side limit is not exactly "10 requests per second", and since it's not explained in the API docs I wouldn't rely on its behavior.

Answer (score 1):

---

This approach is not correct beacuse of Google Server Overload. 
 For more informations see 
 https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15052/how-to-avoid-google-map-geocode-limit#answer-15365

---

By the way, if you wish to proceed anyway, here you can find a code that let you load multiple markers ajax sourced on google maps avoiding OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error.

**I've tested on my onw server and it works!**:

```
var lost_addresses = [];
    geocode_count  = 0;
    resNumber = 0;
    map = new GMaps({
       div: '#gmap_marker',
       lat: 43.921493,
       lng: 12.337646,
    });

function loadMarkerTimeout(timeout) {
    setTimeout(loadMarker, timeout)
}

function loadMarker() { 
    map.setZoom(6);         
    $.ajax({
            url: [Insert here your URL] ,
            type:'POST',
            data: {
                "action":   "loadMarker"
            },
            success:function(result){

                /***************************
                 * Assuming your ajax call
                 * return something like: 
                 *   array(
                 *      'status' => 'success',
                 *      'results'=> $resultsArray
                 *   );
                 **************************/

                var res=JSON.parse(result);
                if(res.status == 'success') {
                    resNumber = res.results.length;
                    //Call the geoCoder function
                    getGeoCodeFor(map, res.results);
                }
            }//success
    });//ajax
};//loadMarker()

$().ready(function(e) {
  loadMarker();
});

//Geocoder function
function getGeoCodeFor(maps, addresses) {
        $.each(addresses, function(i,e){                
                GMaps.geocode({
                    address: e.address,
                    callback: function(results, status) {
                            geocode_count++;        

                            if (status == 'OK') {       

                                //if the element is alreay in the array, remove it
                                lost_addresses = jQuery.grep(lost_addresses, function(value) {
                                    return value != e;
                                });


                                latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
                                map.addMarker({
                                        lat: latlng.lat(),
                                        lng: latlng.lng(),
                                        title: 'MyNewMarker',
                                    });//addMarker
                            } else if (status == 'ZERO_RESULTS') {
                                //alert('Sorry, no results found');
                            } else if(status == 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT') {

                                //if the element is not in the losts_addresses array, add it! 
                                if( jQuery.inArray(e,lost_addresses) == -1) {
                                    lost_addresses.push(e);
                                }

                            } 

                            if(geocode_count == addresses.length) {
                                //set counter == 0 so it wont's stop next round
                                geocode_count = 0;

                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    getGeoCodeFor(maps, lost_addresses);
                                }, 2500);
                            }
                    }//callback
                });//GeoCode
        });//each
};//getGeoCodeFor()
```

Example:

```js
map = new GMaps({
  div: '#gmap_marker',
  lat: 43.921493,
  lng: 12.337646,
});

var jsonData = {  
   "status":"success",
   "results":[  
  {  
     "customerId":1,
     "address":"Via Italia 43, Milano (MI)",
     "customerName":"MyAwesomeCustomer1"
  },
  {  
     "customerId":2,
     "address":"Via Roma 10, Roma (RM)",
     "customerName":"MyAwesomeCustomer2"
  }
   ]
};
   
function loadMarkerTimeout(timeout) {
  setTimeout(loadMarker, timeout)
}

function loadMarker() { 
  map.setZoom(6);
 
  $.ajax({
    url: '/echo/html/',
    type: "POST",
    data: jsonData,
    cache: false,
    success:function(result){

      var res=JSON.parse(result);
      if(res.status == 'success') {
        resNumber = res.results.length;
        //Call the geoCoder function
        getGeoCodeFor(map, res.results);
      }
    }//success
  });//ajax
  
};//loadMarker()

$().ready(function(e) {
  loadMarker();
});

//Geocoder function
function getGeoCodeFor(maps, addresses) {
  $.each(addresses, function(i,e){    
    GMaps.geocode({
      address: e.address,
      callback: function(results, status) {
        geocode_count++;  
        
        console.log('Id: '+e.customerId+' | Status: '+status);
        
        if (status == 'OK') {  

          //if the element is alreay in the array, remove it
          lost_addresses = jQuery.grep(lost_addresses, function(value) {
            return value != e;
          });


          latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
          map.addMarker({
            lat: latlng.lat(),
            lng: latlng.lng(),
            title: e.customerName,
          });//addMarker
        } else if (status == 'ZERO_RESULTS') {
          //alert('Sorry, no results found');
        } else if(status == 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT') {

          //if the element is not in the losts_addresses array, add it! 
          if( jQuery.inArray(e,lost_addresses) == -1) {
            lost_addresses.push(e);
          }

        } 

        if(geocode_count == addresses.length) {
          //set counter == 0 so it wont's stop next round
          geocode_count = 0;

          setTimeout(function() {
            getGeoCodeFor(maps, lost_addresses);
          }, 2500);
        }
      }//callback
    });//GeoCode
  });//each
};//getGeoCodeFor()
```

```css
#gmap_marker {
  min-height:250px;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position: relative; 
  overflow: hidden;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gmaps.js/0.4.24/gmaps.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<div id="gmap_marker"></div> <!-- /#gmap_marker -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of client-side geocoding

```
geocoder.geocode({
    'address': your_address
  }, function (results, status) {
     if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
       var geo_data = results[0];
       // your code ...
   } 
})
```

I would go to server-side geocoding API

```
var apikey = YOUR_API_KEY;
var query = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + address + '&key=' + apikey;
$.getJSON(query, function (data) {
  if (data.status === 'OK') { 
    var geo_data = data.results[0];
  } 
})
```