# Google Maps over query limit

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding

I am getting the "over query limit" from the Google geocodeing API.

I want to try to workaround it if possible. The webpage is available from the outside world, so I would like to execute the "geocoding" function only once for all users every X minutes. So if any new users connect to the web page the "geocoding" should not run again.

I have added the "setInterval" option, I would like to know if it will help me achieve the needed results.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="420">
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }

       .labels {
     color: orange;
     background-color: black;
     font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
     font-size: 10px;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-align: center;
     width: 50px;     
     border: 2px solid black;
     white-space: nowrap;}
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://jquery-xml2json-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.xml2json.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.0.1/src/markerwithlabel.js"></script>
    <script>
var markers = [];
var map = null;

  $.get('Customers.xml', function(xml) {
      var jsonObj = $.xml2json(xml);
        $.each(jsonObj.Marker, function(){
            var stat = this.site_status == "Critical" ? "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png" : "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green-dot.png";
                 var mark = {
                        title: this.title,
                        location: this.site_location,
                        icon: stat
                        }
                markers.push(mark);
        });
        for(var i=0; i< markers.length; i++){
          var maddress = markers[i].location;
          var image = markers[i].icon;
          var custname = markers[i].title;

          window.setInterval(function(){
             geocodeAddress(maddress, image, custname,map)}, 7500);
        } 
});     

function geocodeAddress(maddress, image, custname,map) {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': maddress}, function(results, status) { 
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {   
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(),results[0].geometry.location.lng());
      var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
      var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
      position: myLatlng, map:map, icon: image,labelContent: custname,
       labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
       labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
       labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75}});
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}

function initialize() {
    var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(35.442579,-40.895920);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: chicago,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your  setTimeout call is just delaying all the calls to the geocoder by 7.5 seconds, you need to space them out if you don't want to run into the query limit.

Comment: @geocodezip
By that you mean increase it to more them 7.5 ?
Also, as noted before I am using "setInterval" although there is no major difference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API OVER QUERY LIMIT per second limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014074/google-maps-api-over-query-limit-per-second-limit)

Comment: sorry. setInterval is even worse than setTImeout.  That will keep geocoding each address every 7.5 seconds.

Comment: okay, i will try to change it as in the link you have added.
Thanks.

Comment: Why not just keep the lat and lng in a database and use those to display your markers?

Comment: @geocodezip
Solved it with the advise in the link you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

If customers.xml rarely changes then I would cache the lat/lng values and add them to the customers.xml file. Google allows caching for 30 days. In pseudo code:

```
If ( my customers.xml file changed || last_change > 30 days )
{
    re-execute google API reverse geocoding and save lat/lng results to customers.xml file
}
else
{
    use lat/lng from customers.xml file
}
```