# for loop not iterating through all of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am trying to geocode an array of postcodes from a json file using [gmaps.js](https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/geocoding.html).

There are 101 postcodes in the array however when I loop through them to use with gmaps.js it only iterates through 11. I have tried looking around for answers, however i can't figure it out, everything looks correct, here is my code

```
var getPostcodes = function () {
                    var json = "http://example.co.uk/addresses.json";

                    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    request.open('GET', json, true);

                    request.onload = function () {
                        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
                            // Success!
                            var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

                            //GET POSTCODES IN ARRAY
                            var postcodesArray = [];
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                postcodesArray.push(data[i].from_postcode);
                            }
                            var postcodes = postcodesArray.filter(Boolean);

                            //GET LAT/LONG POSITIONS
                            for (var n = 0; n < postcodes.length; n++) {
                                GMaps.geocode({
                                    address: postcodes[n],
                                    callback: function (results, status) {
                                        if (status == 'OK') {
                                            var location = results[0].geometry.location;

                                            var latitude = parseFloat(location.lat().toFixed(8)),
                                                longitude = parseFloat(location.lng().toFixed(8));

                                            console.log(latitude + ' ' + longitude);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("failed");
                        }
                    };
                    request.send();
                }

                getPostcodes();
```

//EDIT
console log

[image]

//EDIT
codepen link

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gwWgzB

Comment: Did you check your console window for any errors? Once an exception occurs the script stops the execution. Probably in the last iteration it does some property is undefined and generates some kind of exception.

Comment: can you please create fiddle for this

Comment: Is `GMaps.geocode` perhaps rate-limited, and querying it so many times in quick succession from one endpoint is not allowed?

Comment: the reason may be postcodes.length may be  11 ,because postcodes is string

Comment: Look at your console, I am sure there is something in the console or network tab.

Comment: I am not sure, I will try create a fiddle now for better explanation

Comment: try console.log(postcodes); and check for count

Comment: I have checked postcodes.length and it is 101

Comment: I will try load the fiddle as soon as i can

Comment: @Sai Please provide us with whatever is logged into your console, it's the most easy and obvious place to look first.

Comment: I have added a image

Comment: Hello i have put the code on codepen, I was having difficulties with jsfiddle

Comment: Check the `status` parameter. You are getting [`OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingStatusCodes). Here's a dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014074/google-maps-api-over-query-limit-per-second-limit

Comment: Great, thank you for the link, I will look over it to find a solution

Answer (score -1):

Google limits the number of geocoding requests per second. I suggest you to put sleep between consecutive requests.

Comment: `put sleep between consecutive requests` - sleep?

Comment: Is there a limit to how many you can geocode? for some reason it's always after 11 postcodes it stops

Comment: Yes. its 50 request per second and 2500 request per day. But if you don't use api key then it will stop after 11. Sleep between consecutive request means do not iterate all of the postcodes at once.