# Retrieve More Data from Google Map with the radarSearch method and getDetails method

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

May I know how to get more than 10 data results from Google Map when using the radarSearch method that can retrieved 200 results and getDetails method? I want all the marker information is listed down in the white space below the map. However, I only get 10 of it. May I know the problem? The 10 result stay the same and may only change 1 of them when the browser is refresh for a few times.

Here is the code that I used to retrieve the information from Google Map and create the marker. I used the radar Search method to perform the search.

```
   function callback(results, status) {
    if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      console.error(status);
      return;
    }
    for (var i = 0, result; result = results[i]; i++) {
      addMarker(result);
    }
  }

  function addMarker(place) {
    var placesList = document.getElementById('test');
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location,
      icon: {
        url: 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/circle.png',
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 10),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(10, 17)
      }
    });


      service.getDetails(place, function(result, status) {
        if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          console.error(status);
          return;
        }

        iname = result.name;
        iLatitude = [result.geometry.location.lat()];
        iLongitude = [result.geometry.location.lng()];
        iAddress = [result.formatted_address];

      placesList.innerHTML += '<li>' + iname +'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+ iAddress + '</li>';
      });
  }
```

ScreenShot of the result.
[The marker result is nearly 200, while the listed down data only consists of 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ch7k.png)

Comment: There are quotas and rate limits on the place service (check the status returned, you are logging it)

Comment: @geocodezip, Sir, does it due to the getDetails got quota? As what I know from the documentation is the search method got quota, but there are no clear statement about the quota of getDetails. Sir, may you explain in more detail. Thank you.

Comment: All google's service are subject to a quota and a rate limit, `getDetails` is no different (you should be logging the status `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` after the 10th item)

Comment: @geocodezip, Sir can I resolve the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT problem with the solution that you proposed in the forum http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014074/google-maps-api-over-query-limit-per-second-limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem is due to the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT issue, it can be bypass when the time sent request is delayed, setTimeout method can be implemented to avoid OVER_QUERY_LIMIT problem.

Replace with the code below. Can retrieve all the marker data on the map,(currently I have 148 restaurants marker on the Google Map)

```
   service.getDetails(place, function(result, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

        iname = result.name;
        iLatitude = [result.geometry.location.lat()];
        iLongitude = [result.geometry.location.lng()];
        iAddress = [result.formatted_address];

        placesList.innerHTML += '<li>' + iname + ''+ iAddress + '</li>';
        }

        else if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            addMarker(place);
        }, 200);
    }
      });
```