# Error in key generation for draw Poly line in google map

Tags: android, google-maps, polyline, google-polyline

```
 {
      "error_message": "Keyless access to Google Maps Platform is deprecated. Please use an API key with all your API calls to avoid service interruption. For further details please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account",
      "routes": [],
      "status": "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
 }
```

Not able to draw poly line in google map because of this error message and OVER_QUERY_LIMIT status.

Comment: Check [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/articles/usage-limits) && [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14014513/2196176). As you need to append the API key with the URL.

Comment: paste your request parameters and the required code details always

Answer (score 2):

**Please Follow the step To Avoid getting error**

Enable the Following Apis

1 Google map Sdk for android

2 Direction Api

3 Geocoding APi

4 GeoLocation Api

5 Places Api

6 Places Sdk For Android

And Please Create a billing Account It will not take any charges only take 2 INR to check if your not a robot

And please Pass Your Api Key to the URL
(NOTE DONT MAKE YOUR API RESTRICTED)

```
String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters + "&key=" + MY_API_KEY
```

After Completing this Step It will Work..

Comment: without billing account it is possible or not?

Comment: No after 10 request it will throw OVER_LIMIT error again after creating billing account google gives you free credit for one year

Comment: where i need to use this URL ?

Comment: @DharaPatel  please accept the answer to it will help others