# Getting Distance between 2 points returns Error

Tags: c#, google-maps

I am trying to get the distance between 2 points using the Longitude and Latitude in c# now i stumbled into some good codes and using them in my code i am getting this as an exception error :

```
System.Net.WebException: 'Request Not Authorized or Over QueryLimit'
```

My code is looking thus :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using GoogleMaps.LocationServices;
using System.Device.Location;

namespace DistanceCalcConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            getDistancebetween2Points();
        }

        private static void getDistancebetween2Points()
        {
            var originAddress = "Lagos, Nigeria";
            var locationService = new GoogleLocationService();
            var point = locationService.GetLatLongFromAddress(originAddress);

            var latitude1 = point.Latitude;
            var longitude1 = point.Longitude;


            var destinationAddress = "Ibadan, Nigeria";
            var locationService2 = new GoogleLocationService();
            var point2 = locationService2.GetLatLongFromAddress(destinationAddress);

            var latitude2 = point.Latitude;
            var longitude2 = point.Longitude;

            var locA = new GeoCoordinate(latitude1, longitude1);
            var locB = new GeoCoordinate(latitude2, longitude2);
            double distance = locA.GetDistanceTo(locB);
            double finalDistance = distance / 1000;
            Console.Write(finalDistance +" Kilometers");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Does it look like i am missing something? was made to understand that using Googlemaps.Locationservice is free so i should not be expecting this error...

Comment: I am not a Geo expert but found this StackOverflow link which might be helpful --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014074/google-maps-api-over-query-limit-per-second-limit .  Additionally, it appears that the exception you are getting relates to hitting against the service in too short a period which is also mentioned in the Stack link.  Cheers!

Comment: I'm wondering if you use an API key? Please note that API key is required in Google maps platform and without it you will get Unauthorized error messages.

Answer (score 0):

There are few possible reasons for having unauthorized or over query limit error:

1. [Billing not enabled](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project)
2. [Keyless Implementation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)
3. [Self-Imposed usage cap](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage)

If above solutions didn't work or are already done on your end, kindly file a support case via https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support in order to open personalized communication channel as this will need further investigation to address the issue properly.