# GeoCoding - API - OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Tags: google-geocoding-api

We are getting error "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" while invoking GeoCoding - API. We have tried to set the Higher Quota limit but there is no process to carry in the portal.

Kindly guide us to complete this task.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014074/google-maps-api-over-query-limit-per-second-limit

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps API having their own limitations. Check [Google Maps API Quota](https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/quotas) for usage statistics and limitations. 
[Google Maps API Quota Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPsAn.png)

Go for premium plan if you are having heavy usage. Contact me if you need solution.
Google Premium plan details [Google Maps Premium Plan](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing)

Answer (score 0):

this means that you exceeded the Google Maps Platform web services usage limits by sending too many requests per day or e.g. by. sending requests too fast, i.e. too many requests per second.

the above problems can be resolve by two ways:

1.Lowering usage, by optimizing applications to use the web services more efficiently.

2.Increasing usage limits, when possible, by purchasing additional allowance for your Google Maps APIs for Work license.