# Google Maps API v3 geocode, not loading all markers always

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, maps, geocoding

My problem is when I switch beetwen select list. Markers disappear, but not always, they should not disappear. Why?

Maybe here somewhere is problem because I used (I think so) closures.

```
                for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                if (locations[i][1] =='undefined'){ description ='';} else { description = locations[i][1];}
                if (locations[i][2] =='undefined'){ telephone ='';} else { telephone = locations[i][2];}
                if (locations[i][3] =='undefined'){ email ='';} else { email = locations[i][3];}
               if (locations[i][4] =='undefined'){ web ='';} else { web = locations[i][4];}
               if (locations[i][7] =='undefined'){ markericon ='';} else { markericon = locations[i][7];}

               geokoder.geocode
               (
                    { 'address': locations[i][0]+','+locations[i][1]}, (function(i) {
                        return function(results, status)
                        {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                        {

                                marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                                icon: markericon,
                                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                                map: map,
                                title: locations[i][0],
                                desc: description,
                                tel: telephone,
                                email: email,
                                web: web
                            });
                            //środkuje mapę
                            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

                            link = '';
                            bindInfoWindow(marker[i], map, locations[i][0], locations[i][1], telephone, email, web, link);
                        }
                        }})(i)
               );    
            }
```

Here is fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zq7bojd5/3/

Comment: I don't like the way you did this, sorry.  Copying that data multiple times is not the right thing to do.  Starting init() every time you change the select, is not right.  You should keep the same map, but just clear the markers and set new ones.  I'll see if I can give you the same requirements, but different code.

Comment: so how fix it? here I change many init() to one: http://jsfiddle.net/zq7bojd5/4/ but still is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: markers 3, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 are not found by geoLocation at my computer.  Maybe it would be a good idea to add the country to the search request.

EDIT2: geocoder is limited to 10 results.  As this thread points out: you should store the coordinates somewhere; you can't use geocoder for this many locations  [How do I Geocode 20 addresses without receiving an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419219/how-do-i-geocode-20-addresses-without-receiving-an-over-query-limit-response).

---

You'l have some work, but I think this is about what you require.

Look at function getVisibleLocations, to see if the values in the switch are right

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 400px;
      }
      .gm-style-iw {
        overflow: hidden;  /* Google Maps bug; the first time you open an infoWindow, the size is too short, this produces a window with scroll bar */
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script>
      //obiekt geokodowania
      var geokoder;
      //ikonka markera
      var image = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_icon&chld=cafe|FFFF00';
      //obiekt mapy
      var map;
      //tablica markerów
      var markers = [];
      var visibleLocations = [];

      locations = [
        ['Stargard Szczecinski', 'Uslugowa 1a', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', image],
        ['Choszczno', 'Kwiatowa 7', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', image],
        ['Nowogard', '3 Maja 6a', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', image],
        ['Myslibórz', 'Lipowa 18', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', image],
        ['Pyrzyce', 'Narutowicza 6', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', image],
        ['Chojna', 'Jagiellonska 15', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', image],
        ['Walcz', 'Bydgoska 75', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', image],

        ['Bartoszyce','Ketrzynska 37b', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', image],
        ['Braniewo','Królewiecka 61', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', image],
        ['Goldap','Gumbinska 1', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', image],
        ['Ketrzyn','Mazowiecka 17', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', image],
        ['Lidzbark Warminski','Olsztynska 6', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', image],
        ['Lubawa','Fijewo 69', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', image],
        ['Mragowo','Olsztynska 13', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', image],
        ['Nidzica','Dzialdowska 14A', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', image],
        ['Szczytno','Polna 1', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', image],
      ];

      // we only need to search for these locations once.  Let's just search the at the start.
      // we will copy (a pointer to) the marker in locations, as locations[i][9] . 
      // This makes it easy to find which marker belongs to which address
      function searchAllMarkerPositions() {
        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
          if (locations[i][1] =='undefined'){ description ='';} else { description = locations[i][1];}
          if (locations[i][2] =='undefined'){ telephone ='';} else { telephone = locations[i][2];}
          if (locations[i][3] =='undefined'){ email ='';} else { email = locations[i][3];}
          if (locations[i][4] =='undefined'){ web ='';} else { web = locations[i][4];}
          if (locations[i][7] =='undefined'){ markericon ='';} else { markericon = locations[i][7];}
          geokoder.geocode({
            'address': locations[i][0]+','+locations[i][1]}, (function(i) {
               return function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                  markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    icon: markericon,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    // map: map,
                    title: locations[i][0],
                    desc: description,
                    tel: telephone,
                    email: email,
                    web: web
                  });
                  // search for the default markers
                  var visibleLocations = getVisibleLocations(null);
                  if (visibleLocations.indexOf(i) > -1) {
                    markers[i].setMap(map);
                  }
                  else {
                    markers[i].setMap(null);
                  }
                  // we will copy (a pointer to) the marker in locations
                  locations[i][9] = markers[i];
                  // let's center the map to the first marker
                  if (i==0) {
                    map.setCenter(markers[i].getPosition());
                  }
                  // bind the infoWindow
                  bindInfoWindow(markers[i], map, locations[i][0], locations[i][1], locations[i][2], locations[i][3], '');
                  //  // srodkuje mape
                  //  map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
              }
            }})(i)
          );
        }
      }

      // load the map - search all the markers once (store them in var markers) - read the <select> and make the right markers visible
      function init() {
        geokoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.259808, 19.02602),
          zoom: 5,
          zoomControl: true,
          zoomControlOptions: {
              style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
          },
          disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
          mapTypeControl: false,
          scaleControl: false,
          scrollwheel: true,
          panControl: false,
          streetViewControl: false,
          draggable : true,
          overviewMapControl: true,
          overviewMapControlOptions: {
            opened: false,
          },
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        }

        map = new google.maps.Map(
          document.getElementById('map'),
          mapOptions
        );

        searchAllMarkerPositions();
        // handle of the select
        // lokalizacje w zaleznosci od wybranego regionu
        $("#sklepy").change(function () {
          var val = $(this).val();
          var visibleLocations = getVisibleLocations(val);
          updateVisibleMarkers(visibleLocations);
        });
      }
      // Pokazuje chmurke z opisem
      function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, title, desc, telephone, email, web, link) {
        var infoWindowVisible = (function () {
          var currentlyVisible = false;
          return function (visible) {
            if (visible !== undefined) {
              currentlyVisible = visible;
            }
            return currentlyVisible;
          };
        }());
        iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          if (infoWindowVisible()) {
            iw.close();
            infoWindowVisible(false);
          } 
          else {
            // znikanie innych chmurek
            iw.close();
            var html= "<div style='color:#000;background-color:#fff;padding:5px;width:150px;'><h3>Sklep GRENE</h3><h4>"+title+"</h4><p>"+desc+"<p></div>";
            iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:html});
            iw.open(map,marker);
            infoWindowVisible(true);
          }
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(iw, 'closeclick', function () {
          infoWindowVisible(false);
        });
      }


      // reads the visible markers.  Leave the parameter null to get the default.
      function getVisibleLocations(val) {
        switch (val) {
          default:
            var visibleLocations = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];  // the indexes of the locations
            break;
          case "warminsko-mazurskie":
            var visibleLocations = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
            break;
          case "zachodniopomorskie":
            var visibleLocations = [1, 4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 0];  // this looks exactly like de default, but different order.  Correct?
            break;
        }
        return visibleLocations;
      }

      function updateVisibleMarkers(visibleLocations) {
        clearAllMarkers();
        for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
          if (typeof markers[i] == 'undefined') {
            continue;
          }
          if (visibleLocations.indexOf(i) > -1) {
            markers[i].setMap(map);
          }
        }
      }

      function clearAllMarkers() {
        for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
          if (typeof markers[i] == 'undefined') {
            continue;
          }
          markers[i].setMap(null);
        }
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wyszukiwarka">
      <form>
        <label for="sklepy" class="accessibility">Wybierz region</label>
        <select name="sklepy" id="sklepy" class="no-margin">
          <option value="">-- Wybierz region --</option>
          <option value="warminsko-mazurskie">warminsko-mazurskie</option>
          <option value="zachodniopomorskie">zachodniopomorskie</option>
        </select>
        <div id="map"></div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks,but it is not exactly what I want but ok... firstly, my array will be look like: [undefined, undefined, undefined, 44, undefined, 478 ] (index are not incremented by one because they are randomize) but are undefined values in javascript array problem? (Maybe I should ask if undefinied values in THIS case are problem). Secondly(important) why 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 are not found by geoLocation in this script?(3 is)You omitted polish characters but those adresses are true, you can check it here: http://www.geocoderpro.com/en/resources/free-online-geocoder/, but they are not visible on our map

Comment: How about it? Any solution? Everything work if I use coordinates insead of geocoding.

Comment: Yes, you should store the coordinates somewhere.  A problem I wasn't thinking about: geocoder is limited to 10 search results, so that's a problem for this code