# How to handle OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using google maps to draw the path among various location which are stored in database.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/en608jxa/)

While passing 15 geopoints(anything more than 10) am getting status as OVER_QUERY_LIMIT.

I understand that we need to give some milliseconds of time gap when we pass more than 10 geopoints per seconds.

My question is **HOW TO DO THAT..Where to add sleep() or setTimeout() or any other time delay code**

I've tried all,maximum all possibilities provided at SO but failed.As because they are just saying give some time gap between request but how to do that?

Code Snippet:

```
    var markers = [
                        {
                            "title": 'abc',
                            "lat": '17.5061925',
                            "lng": '78.5049901',
                            "description": '1'
                        },                  


                        {
                            "title": 'abc',
                            "lat": '17.50165',
                            "lng": '78.5139204',
                            "description": '2'
                        },
                        .
                        .
                        .
                        .
                        .
                        {
                            "title": 'abc',
                            "lat": '17.4166067',
                            "lng": '78.4853992',
                            "description": '15'
                        }

         ];


    var map;

    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
        zoom: 15    ,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();
    var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

    var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
        map: map,
        strokeColor: '#000000'
    });

    var lat_lng = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i <= markers.length-1; i++)
    {
           var src = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng);
           var des = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i+1].lat, markers[i+1].lng);

            poly.setPath(path);
            service.route({
                origin: src,
                destination: des,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            }, 
           function (result, status)
           {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
                {
  for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length;
       i < len; i++) 
                    {
                        path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);

                    }
                 } 
                 else{

                     if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT)
                     {      
                          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML +="request failed:"+status+"<br>";
                     }                                    

            } 
         });

    }
  });
```

RESULT MAP(OVER_QUERY_LIMIT):

[image: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT]

Comment: I've referred it @Andreas but it didn't mentioned **How to do** It is all about **What to do** which is very difficult for me to pretend.

Answer (score 1):

Google reccomends:

> Lowering usage, by optimizing applications to use the web services more efficiently.
>
> Increasing usage limits, when possible, by purchasing additional allowance for your Google Maps API for Work license.

Also [HERE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits#limitexceeded) there is some workaround that seems to fit what you need in

```
if status == "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT": 
    time.sleep(2)
```

This is written in Phyton, but you can use it as [Pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode), it's easily readable:

```
url = "MAPS_API_WEBSERVICE_URL"
attempts = 0
success = False

while success != True and attempts < 3:
  raw_result = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
  attempts += 1
  # The GetStatus function parses the answer and returns the status code
  # This function is out of the scope of this example (you can use a SDK).
  status = GetStatus(raw_result)
  if status == "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT":
    time.sleep(2)
    # retry
    continue
  success = True

if attempts == 3:
  # send an alert as this means that the daily limit has been reached
  print "Daily limit has been reached"
```

In your `javascript` code, simply set a timeout:

```
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT)
{      
    setTimeout(3000);
}
```

Check the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/en608jxa/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and response @Jordi..Am trying to implement your concept in JScript..I'll tell you when am done with it

Comment: tell me if you have some doubt... I can give you a hand with `javascript` code ;)

Comment: If you edit your answer in jscript which can work with this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/en608jxa/) then that would be of great help.. :)

Comment: you have the working fiddle and the relevant code lines in the update of my answer... hope that helps...

Comment: Hello @Jordi...Thank you so much for your patience,but am sorry to say that still the is path is incomplete.As you can see the source(green-dot) and destination(red-dot) are not met .Path line stops before reaching destination

Comment: Hello @Jordi.. Trust you are doing great..Still I didn't solved this question.. Could you be of any help please..