# Google API and wrong result from its own function directionService

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I' m having this problem , when I load my page and insert Origin and Destination, after clicking the button "locate" it doesn't show anything in the google map, because it says Response is not an object , so I tried to stamp it with console.log and it says Response=null , but if I reload the page and click fast on Locate , then it draws the route.

Here's the code

```
function init(){
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.635636, 17.942414);
    var mapOptions = { zoom: 12, center: latlng  };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function updateMap(){
    init();

    var originGeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var destinationGeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var origin = document.getElementById( "origin" ).value + " Brindisi 72100";
    var destination = document.getElementById( "destination" ).value + " Brindisi 72100";


    var directionsService2 = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    originGeocoder.geocode( { 'address': origin }, function(results, status) {
        if ( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
            var startLatLng = results[0].geometry.location;
            var oLat = startLatLng.lat();
            var oLng = startLatLng.lng();
            document.getElementById('cStart').innerHTML = oLat + " " + oLng;
        }
        else{
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }      
    });

    //Chiamata asincrona alle API per ottenere Lat e Lng dell' indirizzo di destinazione
    destinationGeocoder.geocode( { 'address': destination }, function(results, status) {
        if ( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
            var destLatLng = results[0].geometry.location;
            var dLat = destLatLng.lat();
            var dLng = destLatLng.lng();
            document.getElementById('cDestination').innerHTML = typeof dLat;
            document.getElementById('cDestination').innerHTML = dLat + " " + dLng;
        }
        else{
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }        
    });

    //Salva in req[] le varie distanze tra le paline e la destinazione
    singleObjToStop(origin,destination,function(paline,req,reqO){
        console.log("1");
        //Trova la palina più vicina alla destinazione
        calcSingleDis(paline,req,reqO,function(w2,w1){
            console.log("2");
            //Disegna i waypoints(?)
            reqEnd(origin,destination,w1,w2,function(request){
                console.log("3");
                directionsService2.route(request, function(response, status) {
                    console.log("4");
                    console.log(response);
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                        var route = response.routes[0];
                        var summaryPanel = document.getElementById("distance");
                        summaryPanel.innerHTML = "";
                        // For each route, display summary information.
                        for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
                            var routeSegment = i + 1;
                            summaryPanel.innerHTML += "<b>Route Segment: " + routeSegment + "</b><br />";
                            summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + " to ";
                            summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + "<br />";
                            summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + " ";
                            summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].duration.text +  "<br /><br />" ;
                        }
                        computeTotalDistance(response);
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log("ENTRA QUA STRONZO");
                        console.log("Fermata partenza = " + w1);
                        console.log("Fermata arrivo = " + w2);
                    }
                });
                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            });
        });
    });
}

function singleObjToStop(origin,destination,callback){
    var data=<?php echo $data; ?>;
    var a,b,i=0;
    var paline = new Array();
    var req = new Array(); 
    var reqO = new Array();
    var num = <?php echo $n; ?>;
    $.each(data, function(fieldName, fieldValue) {
        a=fieldValue.geoLat;
        b=fieldValue.geoLong;
        a=parseFloat(a);
        b=parseFloat(b);
        paline[i]=new google.maps.LatLng(a,b);

        req[i] = {
            origin:paline[i],
            destination:destination,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
        };

        reqO[i] = {
            origin:origin,
            destination:paline[i],
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
        };

        i++;
        if(i==num){
            callback(paline,req,reqO);
        }
    });
}

function calcSingleDis(paline, req, reqO, callback) {
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var c = 10000000;
    var w2 = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
    var w1 = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
    var num = <?php echo $n; ?>;
    var j = (num - 1);
    var t;

    var cO = 10000000;
    var numO = <?php echo $n; ?>;
    var jO = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < num; j++) {
        t = 0;
        directionsService.route(req[j], function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                //directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                var troute = response.routes[0];
                var dis = parseFloat((troute.legs[0].distance.text).replace(",", "."));

                document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = dis;

                //se distanza minore di quella minore trovata fin ora la cambia
                if (dis < c) {
                    w2 = paline[j - num];
                    c = dis;
                }

                if (t == (num - 1)) {
                    console.log("QUA ENTRA LOL");

                    for (jO = 0; jO < numO; jO++) {
                        console.log("E NON ENTRA MANNAC");
                        t = 0;
                        directionsService.route(reqO[jO], function(response, status) {
                            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                                console.log("E NON ENTRA MANNAC22222");
                                //directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                                var troute = response.routes[0];
                                var disO = parseFloat((troute.legs[0].distance.text).replace(",", "."));

                                document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = dis;

                                //se distanza minore di quella minore trovata fin ora la cambia
                                if (disO < cO) {
                                    w1 = paline[jO - numO];
                                    cO = disO;
                                }

                                if (t == (numO - 1)) {
                                    console.log("W1 = " + w1);
                                    console.log(response);
                                    callback(w2, w1);

                                }
                            }
                            jO++;
                            t++;
                        });
                    }

                }
            }
            j++;
            t++;
        });
    }
}

function reqEnd(origin,destination,w1,w2,callback){
    var request = {
        origin:origin,
        destination:destination,
          waypoints: [{location: w1} , {location: w2}],
          //waypoints: [{location: w2}],
          optimizeWaypoints: true,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
    };
    callback(request);
}

function computeTotalDistance(result) {
    var totalDist = 0;
    var totalTime = 0;
    var myroute = result.routes[0];
    for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
        totalDist += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
        totalTime += myroute.legs[i].duration.value;   
    }
    totalDist = totalDist / 1000.
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "total distance is: "+ totalDist + " km<br>total time is: " + (totalTime / 60).toFixed(2) + " minutes";
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener( window, 'load', init );
```

Comment: Where's the 'locate' button - do you have some kind of event listener attached to it?  It's not apparent in your code.

Comment: Yes , with the locate button i call the function UpdateMap()

Comment: `response` is null. What about `status`? Did you log that too?

Comment: Solved , the problem was the limit of the query , more than 6 per second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is related to the limit of query that you can use with Google Maps API v3.
You can take a look here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/faq#google_maps_api_services

You probably do lots of requests to the API with your program, while you have quite restrictive limits as you can see from google Q&A.

> Applications should throttle requests to avoid exceeding usage limits,
>   bearing in mind these apply to each client ID regardless of how many
>   IP addresses the requests are sent from.
>
> You can throttle requests by putting them through a queue that keeps
>   track of when are requests sent. With a rate limit or 10 QPS (queries
>   per second), on sending the 11th request your application should check
>   the timestamp of the first request and wait until 1 second has passed.
>   The same should be applied to daily limits.
>
> Even if throttling is implemented correctly applications should watch
>   out for responses with status code OVER_QUERY_LIMIT. If such response
>   is received, use the pause-and-retry mechanism explained in the Usage
>   limits exceeded section above to detect which limit has been exceeded.

You could find useful: [How do I Geocode 20 addresses without receiving an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419219/how-do-i-geocode-20-addresses-without-receiving-an-over-query-limit-response)

Comment: How can you say that with the information provided in the question?

Comment: He use a for twice, with 2 geocode and another request for final path, so with just 7 directions he should go over query limit, and none use a for for just 1 cycle

Comment: Thanks , it was the problem!!

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps API provides a geocoder class for geocoding and reverse geocoding dynamically from user input. [read more](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) check Geolocation [demo here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation) and more HTML5 Geolocation to [check here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)