# What is the best way to convert latitude/longitudes into a street address at a high scale in batch?

Tags: google-geocoder, geocode, reversegeocodelocation

The existing questions are related to real-time needs; the answers are API-based solutions. 
These solutions are not well suited to do a large batch task.

- [Convert Latitude/Longitude To Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603738/convert-latitude-longitude-to-address)

This solution suggests caching google results for a short time:

- [what is the best geocode to get long and lot for a street address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34022948/what-is-the-best-geocode-to-get-long-and-lot-for-a-street-address)

**Is there a better solution? If there is not a good open-source dataset available for this then do you know of a good paid service?**

Answer (score 1):

[Open Street Map](http://openstreetmap.org) has the [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Development_overview) database which might do what you need.