# Wordpress wp_remote_get google maps link

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to gelocate a location

If i use this one  `$response = wp_remote_get( $url );` I am getting the (`Please use an API key with all your API calls to avoid service interruption. For further details please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account", "results" : [], "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" }` ) error from google But if i am trying to use the hard coded link it works:

```
 $response2 = wp_remote_get( "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=long%2Bisland%2Bcity%2Bny%2B11103%2Busa&key=AIzaSyBdjwjKwkVOkZZDftw4VWMenxE5bnUeC2E&region=US&language=EN&sansor=false");
```

Any ideea why ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a two way,

1. Use within double quote, This is just a try,

   $response = wp_remote_get("$url");
2. I can see OVER_QUERY_LIMIT in your response from geocoder. The Google geocoder has quota and rate limits. The best solution is to delay when you get OVER_QUERY_LIMIT errors and then retry.

If query limit is the problem try below options,

1. [OVER_QUERY_LIMIT in Google Maps API v3: How do I pause/delay in
   Javascript to slow it down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792916/over-query-limit-in-google-maps-api-v3-how-do-i-pause-delay-in-javascript-to-sl)
2. [How do I Geocode 20 addresses without receiving an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT
   response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419219/how-do-i-geocode-20-addresses-without-receiving-an-over-query-limit-response)